# IIdConvention "overrides" IAutoMapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm using a specific convention for my Id tables and I'd like to override the way the ID of a specific entity is mapped. In this scenario, most of the entities should a key on the form Class+ID (ex.: EmployeeId, DepartmentId, etc), but I'd like to use a specific property for a couple of enties. So, I've added a default convention rule:

```
class MyPrimaryKeyConvention:IIdConvention{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance) {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        instance.GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }
}
```

And then, I thought I could override the mappings of the "special" EmployeeShortInfo class by doing something like this:

```
public class EmployeeShortInfoIdOverride: IAutoMappingOverride<Dtos.EmployeeShortInfo> {
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Dtos.EmployeeShortInfo> mapping) {
        mapping.Id(e => e.EmployeeId);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, fluent will try to use EmployeeShortInfoId instead of using the EmployeeId property. Shouldn't IAutoMappingOverride override the default convention of a class?

thanks.

Comment: Same problem. Any luck fixing it?